# How to allow Azure cloud service to access storage and deny other requests

Tags: azure, cloud, storage

How can I protect Azure storage and allow access only to certain Azure Cloud services? Currently, we have a web and worker roles running in Azure cloud Service (Classic) deployment and we connect to storage using access key, but we don't have any filtering in place.

What I want is to allow only certain deployments to connect to storage and a couple of users from trusted IP addresses.

I tried creating a VNet in azure and updating project configuration but without success. Link: [How to connect Azure Web Sites to a Worker Role (TCP) through a (regional) vnet? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475988/how-to-connect-azure-web-sites-to-a-worker-role-tcp-through-a-regional-vnet)